# Why are grid items not centered?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

For some reason two input ranges are making the top two items in the grid off centered.

I am assuming this is because of their shadow DOM styling. Is this actually the case?

**Does anybody know why the ranges are making items A and B off centered?**

**[Here is a codepen.](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/QOeKLP)**

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #0d0d0d; }

#center{width:2px;height:100%;position:absolute;left:calc(50% - 1px);background:red;}

#grid {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a b b"
    "c c c d"
    "e e e f"
    "g g g g"
    ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: dotted yellow 1px;
}

#a, #b { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }

#a, #b, #d, #f, #g { background: #1a1a1a; }

#a { grid-area: a; }
#b { grid-area: b; }
#c { grid-area: c; }
#d { grid-area: d; }
#e { grid-area: e; }
#f { grid-area: f; }
#g { grid-area: g; }
```

```html
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="grid">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <input type="range" id="c">
  <div id="d"></div>
  <input type="range" id="e">
  <div id="f"></div>
  <div id="g">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

When you don't define the grid column widths using `grid-template-columns` (for explicit grids) or `grid-auto-columns` (for implicit grids), the width of each column is left to `auto`. This means that the widths are determined by the content.

You've defined the layout with `grid-template-areas`:

```
grid-template-areas:  "a a b b"
                      "c c c d"
                      "e e e f"
                      "g g g g" ;
```

But you haven't defined the columns, so they are left to their own devices.

In this case, the `auto` columns result in a visual (but not actual) misalignment in your grid:

*As seen in Chrome:*

[image]

---

### Solutions

Since you are working with a four-column implicit grid, you can add this rule to your grid container to fix the problem.

```
grid-auto-columns: 1fr
```

Now, instead of the container distributing space based on content size, it distributes space evenly among columns.

*Chrome, with the adjustment above:*

[image]

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzvzYr)

You can also fix the problem with this rule:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
```

[image]

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOgOBG)

---

### Browser Variations

By the way, your layout renders differently across Grid-supporting browsers.

*Chrome*

[image]

*Firefox*

[image]

*Edge*

[image]

(I didn't test in Safari.)

Basically, in Firefox and Edge the range input looks like its locked into the first column and doesn't honor the `grid-template-areas` rule.

This is because of a default setting on this type of input set by these browsers:

*Firefox*

[image]

So basically these inputs are set to `width: 12em`.

To fix the problem, add this to your code:

```
input { width: auto }
```

Now everything should work across all Grid-supporting browsers.

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbqbrV)

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #0d0d0d; }

#center{width:2px;height:100%;position:absolute;left:calc(50% - 1px);background:red;}

#grid {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a a b b"
    "c c c d"
    "e e e f"
    "g g g g"
    ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: dotted yellow 1px;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* NEW */
}
input { width: auto; } /* NEW */

#a, #b { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }

#a, #b, #d, #f, #g { background: #1a1a1a; }

#a { grid-area: a; }
#b { grid-area: b; }
#c { grid-area: c; }
#d { grid-area: d; }
#e { grid-area: e; }
#f { grid-area: f; }
#g { grid-area: g; }
```

```html
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="grid">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <input type="range" id="c">
  <div id="d"></div>
  <input type="range" id="e">
  <div id="f"></div>
  <div id="g">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's so strange. i could've sworn i set `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` and it did not seem to effect it, though now it's working o: thank you so much for such an informative answer

Comment: i actually was using an explicit width for the inputs which i removed for the MVP. however, it doesn't even really matter cuz this is a tool i'm building only for myself :)